# Polynomial Function application

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The rabbit population on a small island is observed to be given by the function 
$$P(t)=120t-0.4t^{ 4 }+1000$$

where $t$ is the time (in months) since observations of the island began.

When is the maximum population attained, and what is the maximum population?

When does the rabbit population disappear from the island?

I graphed this function and found that the max population is attained $4$ months afterwards and it was at $1380$ rabbits.

I also found that the population disappears after 8.5 months.

Am I correct? and how would I solve this algebraically. I tried using the discriminant but my answer differed from what the graph seemed to show..

Comment: do you know derivatives and their relationship with local maxima/minima of a function?

Comment: Are you talking about this?
$$f(-\frac { b }{ 2a } )$$

Comment: Do you know what derivatives are?

Comment: For disappearance, if we use the model we need to solve a quartic.  There *is* an old algebraic formula for solving the quartic (Cardano-Ferrari) but it is not useful, and it is best to solve the equation by a numerical approximation method.  For practical purposes, graphing is adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a precalculus soln. Note that it is enough to find when we have the maximum of  $\frac52(P(t)-1000)=t(300-t^3)$. In turn, this is when we have the max of $3t^3(300-t^3)^3$.  Now this is the product of four terms with a constant sum, so it gets maximum when all the terms are equal, I.e when $t^3=75$.

Comment: +1, not surprised to see an inequality approach to your answer.

Comment: @KimJongUn ;) guilty as charged...

Answer (score 1):

Since $$P'(t)=120-1.6t^3$$
we have$$P'(t)=0 \iff t=\sqrt[3]{75}\approx 4.217.$$
Since $P(t)$ is increasing for $t\lt \sqrt[3]{75}$ and is decreasing for $t\gt \sqrt[3]{75}$, we know that the maximum is attained at $t=\sqrt[3]{75}$, so the maximum population is
$$P(\sqrt[3]{75})=120\cdot \sqrt[3]{75}-0.4\cdot (\sqrt[3]{75})^4+1000\approx 1379.545.$$

Comment: This seems to be much more complicated than reading the information from the graph..